# how to solve Jenkins Build Failed Error :MSB4041

Tags: msbuild

I have build this project as .Net standard project and i am facing this error issue in jenkins when I build this project:

> C:\Users\tahab.jenkins\workspace\Mondaytest\Calculator\Calculator.csproj(1,1):
>   error MSB4041: The default XML namespace of the pr.oject must be the
>   MSBuild XML namespace. If the project is authored in the MSBuild 2003
>   format, please add
>   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" to the
>    element. If the project has been authored in the old 1.0 or
>   1.2 format, please convert it to MSBuild 2003 format

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The default XML namespace of the project must be the MSBuild XML namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42509313/the-default-xml-namespace-of-the-project-must-be-the-msbuild-xml-namespace)

Comment: I voted to close as duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42509313/the-default-xml-namespace-of-the-project-must-be-the-msbuild-xml-namespace.  For some reason Google gave me this one first.  With zero up votes I have no idea if solutions worked here.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you use recent versions of the MSBuild task you use to build your project.

You need too use the Visual Studio 2017 (Build Tools, Full, ..) version of MSBuild - which is local to the Visual Studio installation - to build your project.

You may need to confiure the path to MSBuild, which would be - depending on the version installed on the build gent - similar to

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe
```

This error happens if you try to build new projects with older versions of Visual Studio / MSBuild or even with the old version of MSBuild that is part of .NET Framework.