# How do I solve error MSB4041 (VS2017, C#, MSBuild, SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation, SpecRun)?

Tags: c#, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

I have an automation test suite, attempting to use SpecRun to run tests in parallel. It appears that rather than being able to run tests in Test Explorer, I need to instead run them using the provided "runtests.cmd" file...

```
@pushd %~dp0

@where /q msbuild

@IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
    echo "MSBuild is not in your PATH. Please use a developer command prompt!"
    goto :end
) ELSE (
    MSBuild.exe "C:\Users\me\source\repos\OurAutomation\src\OurAutomation.csproj"
)

@if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto end

@cd ..\packages\SpecRun.Runner.*\tools\net45

@set profile=%1
@if "%profile%" == "" set profile=Default

@if exist "%~dp0\bin\Debug\%profile%.srprofile" (
    SpecRun.exe run "%profile%.srprofile" --baseFolder "%~dp0\bin\Debug" --log "specrun.log" %2 %3 %4 %5
) else (
    SpecRun.exe run --baseFolder "%~dp0\bin\Debug" --log "specrun.log" %2 %3 %4 %5
)

:end

@popd

pause
```

...the pause statement is something I added in to keep the console open to see the errors.

The errors are:

```
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 4.7.3056.0
[Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.42000]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Build started 08/07/2019 11:15:06.
Project "C:\Users\me\source\repos\OurAutomation\src\OurAutomation.csproj" on node 1 (defau
lt targets).
C:\Users\me\source\repos\OurAutomation\src\packages\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.3.0.220\build\Sp
ecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.props(1,1): error MSB4041: The default XML namespace of the project must be the MSBuild
 XML namespace. If the project is authored in the MSBuild 2003 format, please add xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/d
eveloper/msbuild/2003" to the <Project> element. If the project has been authored in the old 1.0 or 1.2 format, please
convert it to MSBuild 2003 format. [C:\Users\me\source\repos\OurAutomation\src\OurAutomati
on.csproj]
Done Building Project "C:\Users\me\source\repos\OurAutomation\src\OurAutomation.csproj" (d
efault targets) -- FAILED.


Build FAILED.

"C:\Users\me\source\repos\OurAutomation\src\OurAutomation.csproj" (default target) (1) ->
  C:\Users\me\source\repos\OurAutomation\src\packages\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.3.0.220\build\
SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.props(1,1): error MSB4041: The default XML namespace of the project must be the MSBui
ld XML namespace. If the project is authored in the MSBuild 2003 format, please add xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com
/developer/msbuild/2003" to the <Project> element. If the project has been authored in the old 1.0 or 1.2 format, pleas
e convert it to MSBuild 2003 format. [C:\Users\me\source\repos\OurAutomation\src\OurAutoma
tion.csproj]

    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.02
```

I've set the system environment variable PATH to look for MSBuild.exe in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 (this is the latest version I have).

I tried to do as the error suggested, and found that both OurAutomation.csproj and OurAutomation.csproj.user files already have:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
```

So that's the simple fix out of the way - no fix at all, because the Project tag already has the required attribute and value!

I've been on several websites looking for an alternative solution. Others are saying that they had this problem when upgrading from VS2015 to 2017 (they changed from using project.json to *.csproj). However I have not upgraded. I created my project in VS2017. Target framework: .NET Framework 4.7.2, Output type: Class Library.

Not sure if SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation is introducing a conflict here, but I do need it.

Please do you know how I would go about fixing this? Running out of ideas.

Thank you.

Comment: Starting from VisualStudio 2015 MSBuild is provided as part of IDE (or build tools), you should use this version, e.g. c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure deployment: error MSB4041: The default XML namespace of the project must be the MSBuild XML namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58617182/azure-deployment-error-msb4041-the-default-xml-namespace-of-the-project-must-b)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The default XML namespace of the project must be the MSBuild XML namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42509313/the-default-xml-namespace-of-the-project-must-be-the-msbuild-xml-namespace)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pavel Anikhouski's answer was the solution, thank you!

"Starting from VisualStudio 2015 MSBuild is provided as part of IDE (or build tools), you should use this version, e.g. c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\".

Comment: Hi Zuno, thanks for your sharing and you can consider marking it as answer. Though the workaround is not complex, but the error message is quite seldom to see, so I think it do help those who encounter similar issue easily find it.A reminder:(

Comment: Er... I posted this reply as an answer? It says "1 Answer" above my post... am I missing something?

Comment: Hi. what's the entire error message? Maybe [the rule](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) needs 48 hours:)