# Unable to install Entity Framework v6.3.0

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to install Entity Framework v6.3.0 to be used with a sqlite database.
I use this to install the EF in my project:

```
Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 6.3.0
```

But I get an error:

[image]

In my past project, I'm installing the EF in my project with out encountering this error. By the way I'm using VS2012.

Comment: Maybe you can follow this steps to install it: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/bnaya/2013/10/21/how-to-start-working-with-ef-6-on-vs-2012/ It's an alternative way than yours.

Comment: @Presi Will try this.

Comment: @Presi Still not working :(

Comment: Have you tried to follow the error details? Btw, in which project type do you install this package?

Comment: [this is a bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58342168/1466046) which is fixed in 6.4 (preview)

Comment: have you tried the 6.4 preview?

Comment: 6.4.0 stable is now out