# Web API project failing to deploy on Azure App Service using Kudu deployments

Tags: azure, msbuild, kudu, azure-appservice

I am using Visual Studio 2019, my Web API project builds and runs fine locally. But, when trying to deploy on Azure App Service it fails with the following error

`D:\home\site\repository\src\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.Toolset.3.6.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.Toolset.props(2,1): error MSB4041: The default XML namespace of the project must be the MSBuild XML namespace. If the project is authored in the MSBuild 2003 format, please add xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" to the <Project> element. If the project has been authored in the old 1.0 or 1.2 format, please convert it to MSBuild 2003 format. [D:\home\site\repository\src\Verify.WebApi\Verify.WebApi.csproj]`

I checked my .csporj file it already has MSBuild 2003 format.
I also installed the latest nuget packages `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform`, `Microsoft.Net.Compilers` and `Microsoft.Net.Compilers.Toolset`.

Azure App Service is using MSBuild 14.0 to build my project.

Can someone help in resolving this issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42509313/the-default-xml-namespace-of-the-project-must-be-the-msbuild-xml-namespace

Comment: ```D:\home\site\repository\src\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.Toolset.3.6.0\tasks\net472\Microsoft.Managed.Core.targets(60,27): error MSB4184: The expression """.GetPathsOfAllDirectoriesAbove()" cannot be evaluated. Method 'System.String.GetPathsOfAllDirectoriesAbove' not found. [D:\home\site\repository\src\Verify.WebApi\Verify.WebApi.csproj]``` now getting this one. Fixed the earlier one by updating MsBuild version to 15.0